# Can pytest or any testing tool in python generate the unit test automatically?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I started writing pytest for the source code I have. For this I see the code and in test I check if that piece of code returns expected value.
Is there any way to automatically generate test cases for python code, positive and parameterized so that it doesn't take much time if the source code is huge

Comment: A tool that can properly unit test a function must have the intelligence to  understand the logic of the function. Then it could just implement it on its own.

Comment: See https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#apply-indirect-on-particular-arguments for parameterising pytest tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate test cases using Pytest, but you can use tools like [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to randomise the particular values that your test cases are given. You still need to specify what cases you want to test though, as well as giving a definition for how it should generate the parameters.

Generally, computers aren't smart enough to know what we want a function to do, so there's no way they can tell whether we intentionally added certain behaviours into our code or whether they are just bugs. Tools like [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) and [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/index.html#) can help catch questionable code, but it's still up to you whether that code is correct or not - they can't know for certain.

Comment: A tool could at least do the tedious job of creating the skeleton, folders, files... Also see related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77409726/ho-to-generate-unit-tests-for-python-in-pycharm-using-src-and-test-folder-struct